# ArrayList Type no longer supported in .NET 3.5 upwards?

Tags: asp.net

I imported System.Collections namespace in my class, but I still cant use ArrayList type. The code editor says the "class not found". I am using VS2008 & VS2010.

So has MS stopped support for this type in framworks 3.5 and upwards ?

Answer (score 3):

[ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) is still supported in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0. From MSDN:

> ## ArrayList Class
>
> Implements the [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.
>
> **Namespace:**  System.Collections
> **Assembly:**  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)
>
> ...
>
> ## Version Information
>
> **.NET Framework**
>
> Supported in: 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0

Remember that it's not a generic type so you can't write `ArrayList<Foo>`. You should use `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a List instead ?

```
List<myObject> variable = new List<myObject>();
```

Comment: Also you can use the IList interface if your planning on letting other users use your assembly.

IList<myObject> variable = new List<myObject>();

Answer (score 1):

IIRC they haven't but you should really use `List<T>` in System.Collections.Generic.